# multiple one sample t.test with ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, t-test

If I want to see if the mean of 3 different groups is above a specific threshold instead of doing 3 on-sample ttest can I use anova?

So instead of 3

```
t.test(data_1$weight, mu = 100, alternative = 'greater') 

t.test(data_2$weight, mu = 100, alternative = 'greater') 

t.test(data_3$weight, mu = 100, alternative = 'greater')
```

can I use anova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the way you have outlined with the 3 one-sample t-tests, given that none of the [t-test assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Assumptions) is violated, is a fine way to go.

There are some other alternatives such as various [interval estimates of population means](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat505/node/61/).

If you want to try the ANOVA then yes, you can fit a model with one factor and then get confidence intervals of the predicted values:

```
## your hypothetical dataset:
weight1 <- rnorm(100,150,2)
weight2 <- rnorm(120,200,20)
weight3 <- rnorm(200,105,1)

dfr     <- data.frame(value = c(weight1,
                                weight2,
                                weight3),
                      population = c(rep("pop1",100),
                                     rep("pop2",120),
                                     rep("pop3",200))
                      )

## model
model   <- lm(value ~ population, data = dfr)

## Predictions
to_pred <- data.frame(population = c("pop1", "pop2" , "pop3"))

## The confidence intervals for weights for each of the 3 populations
predictions <- data.frame(pop = to_pred,
                          predict(model, newdata = to_pred, int = "p", level = 0.95))

predictions
# population      fit       lwr      upr
# 1       pop1 149.8474 129.36860 170.3262
# 2       pop2 200.3777 179.91575 220.8396
# 3       pop3 105.0013  84.57322 125.4294
```

So for my example, population 3 can go below 100 because "lwr" of pop3 is 84.57. 
You can change the "level" parameter if you want to change the significance level